# Twitter login without social framework

Tags: ios, twitter

I am trying to implement twitter login in my ios app. I do not want to use social frame work. I have tried all ways to twitter login but unfortunately this not working. Mainly i am facing the callback url issue in it. Can you please guys help me.

I have tried this url as well

http://codegerms.com/login-with-twitter-example-with-ios-tutorial-using-oauth/

but mainly i am facing the callback issue. Can any one please suggest other plugin.

Comment: use FHSTwitterengine, u need any help i hope with u

Answer (score 2):

To get the user's information from Twitter, you can use **OAuth.io**'s iOS SDK:
https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-ios

After having created an account on https://oauth.io, and added Twitter as a provider, you'll be able to get the user's info quite easily. You just need to follow these steps:

#### **1** Install the framework through Cocoa Pods, or manually

Via Cocoa pod:

```
$ pod install "OAuth.io"
```

Manually:

Just get the `OAuthiOS.framework` file [here](https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-ios/tree/master/Dist) and install it like any other framework.

#### **2** Insert the header reference

Add `#import <OAuthiOS/OAuthiOS.h>` in your ViewController.

#### **3** Set the view controller as delegate to OAuthIODelegate:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController<OAuthIODelegate>
//[...]
@end
```

#### **4** Initialize and launch an authentication popup in the ViewController:

```
OAuthIOModal *oauthioModal = [[OAuthIOModal alloc] initWithKey:@"your_app_public_key" delegate:self];
[oauthioModal showWithProvider:@"twitter"];
```

#### **5** Implement the following delegate method to get a Request Object, that lets you retrieve the user's information, thanks to the `me` method:

```
- (void)didReceiveOAuthIOResponse:(OAuthIORequest *)request
{
    [_request me:nil success:^(NSDictionary *output, NSString *body, NSHTTPURLResponse 
    *httpResponse)
     {
         NSLog(@"name: %@", [output objectForKey:@"name"]);
     }];
}
```

To get more information about the iOS SDK, feel free to check out the guide here:

https://oauth.io/getting-started?ios&None

You can also follow a git based tutorial here:

https://oauth.io/docs/tutorials/client/ios

And find the reference documentation of the SDK here:

https://oauth.io/docs/api-reference/client/ios

Note that OAuth.io also open sourced their core in the oauthd project (check out the repo here: https://github.com/oauth-io/oauthd)

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

rmaddy can you exlain in detail what problem you are facing , I have also followed this tutorial and successfully, I am getting the access token, Try to put breakpoint in your code, You might haven't changed the callback URL in the code, Let me explain you a little using an image

First you should put a break point here in the following function

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType

Now run application and enter your login credentials in, After you have successfully got the request token then you will be redirected to your redirect URL and then you will get the access token
[image]

You program must be not entering in this if condition, try changing this code, to yours callback string, If still you have problem, Let me know in details, I will help you to solve this