# Unable to integrate twitter login using Twitter+OAuth?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, twitter, twitter-oauth

I’m building an app where i want to implement twitter login.I want to fetch user basic profile Information.
I am trying to integrate twitter functionality using Twitter outh library https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone.

And i found an tutorial on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MlGI_vB0--o 
which helps me how to integrate twitter into your project using above library,But problem is when i add the
Twitter+OAuth into my project it gives an error.

```
Error:/Users/rohit/Desktop/Master/Twitter+OAuth/MGTwitterEngine/MGTwitterEngineGlobalHeader.h:17:10: 'Cocoa/Cocoa.h' file not found
```

How can i handle this error,help is appreciated.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25178919/twitter-login-without-social-framework/25179346#25179346 would u need any assistance i surely hope with u

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have implemented quite a few third party for twitter integration . But STTwitter is the best https://github.com/nst/STTwitter  Easy to use and serves all purpose

Comment: Thanks i have used library you have suggested,its working fine,but i want to know two thing:                                                                1.How can i know a user is already login from twitter in my app.        2.how can i fetch user basic profile information like name,image ,age,location etc.

Comment: @Daljeet u can't fetch image ,age,location in twitter

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik that is i want to know how i can fetch user profile information by using this library,if you help me by an example or any simple tutorial it will be great.

Comment: @daljeet u need the single user authentication or multiple user login from twitter

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I need multiple user can login twitter.

Comment: hmm, it is possible (this method is used for native only no need of third parties,if use the third party u can access with login in modal view controller only)  i give the answer, but u can  fetch only user user name and user id only got it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62721/discussion-between-daljeet-and-anbu-karthik).